# c++ class returning pointer to member to be used as array

Tags: c++

```
class vector3
{
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
public:
    vector3( float x, float y, float z ) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    // returning pointer to first member to use it as array.
    // assumes that data layout is sizeof(float) by sizeof(float) by sizeof(float)
    // and their order is not changed.
    float* ptr() { return &x; }
    // implicit casting version of ptr()
    operator float*() { return ptr(); }

};

...

vector3 v(1,2,3);
float x = v[0];
float y = v[1];
float z = v[2];
```

Will it be valid on any platform and any compiler setting?
I found this working under visual studio 2013 correctly,
but I'm having a feeling that this is quite horribly wrong.

Comment: Since the compiler can order members of an array freely, without packing, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feeling is correct.

But what's the point? Why you don't you just have an array member rather than 3 individual `float` members?

```
class vector3
{
private:
    std::array<float, 3> data;
public:
    vector3( float x, float y, float z ) : data( {x, y, z } ) {}
    float* ptr() { return data.data(); }
    operator float*() { return ptr(); }
};
```

This uses C++11, but you can achieve the same thing with C++03:

```
class vector3
{
private:
    float data[3];
public:
    vector3( float x, float y, float z )
    {
        data[0] = x;
        data[1] = y;
        data[2] = z;
    }
    float* ptr() { return data; }
    operator float*() { return ptr(); }
};
```

And of course, the biggest question is: Why don't you just use `std::vector` or `std::array` directly? Your class seems to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you should prohibit yourself from returning pointer/non-const references of your private data members.

Essential purpose of encapsulation is that state of object ( i.e data members ) can only be changed through member functions defined for that class.By returning pointers to data member you are creating another path for changing state which is definitely not a good idea.

If efficiency is the main concern then you can return const references.

Comment: In container classes you will often find exceptions to this rule. `std::vector::operator[]` is a prominent example. It returns a reference to an internally stored element so that you can write `v[1] = x;`. In fact, it even gives you full access to the underlying array. All things considered, it always depends on what your class really wants to represent. A `std::vector` is meant to encapsulate an array; the underlying data is not an implementation detail but part of the documentation, so you cannot and should not hide it from the public interface.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes agreed. It always depends on what you are designing. One aspect of container class is to provide a means to modify what it stores.So, in that case it's justified